# Error Mostrar cola (COLA CIRCULAR)

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

Tengo problemas con mostrar la cola, esta esta compuesta por una cadena de caracteres tipo string, al ejecutar insertar lo hace correctamente al igual que la funcion pop que ya probe (por cuestiones del espacio no puedo poner aqui) y después al mostrar los elementos, solo me muestra la primera letra del string, no se si sea por que no estoy mandando bien toda la cadena o si sera por como mande la cadena ala funcion, bueno de ya muchas gracias

```
#define max 100
char elem=0,belem=-1,c=0; 
struct ccircular{
char a;
};

int pop(struct ccircular *aux,char x[],int num)
{
if(c==0)
{
    printf("COLA LLENA jajaja XD\n"); return 0;
}
c--; 
elem=elem%num;
strcpy((aux+elem)->a, x);
printf("\nElemento eliminado: %s\n",x); elem++;
}

void muestracola(struct ccircular *aux,char x[],int num)
{   

if(c==0)
{
printf("La cola esta Vacia\n"); return; 
}
char i=elem,j=0;
if(elem>belem)
for(i=elem; i<num; i++)
{
    *x=(aux+i)->a;
    printf("[%s]",x); j++;

}
else
    for(i=elem; i<=belem; i++)
    {
    *x=(aux+i)->a;
    printf("[%s]",x); j++;
    }
    if(j!=c)
        {
            for(i=0; i<c-j; i++)
            {
                *x=(aux+i)->a;
                printf("[%s]",x);
            }
        }
    printf("\n");
}
```

aqui el main

```
 int main()
 {
 struct ccircular *aux;
 char x[20];int num,p,ch;
 printf("De que tamaño quiere la cola\n");
 scanf("%d",&num);system("cls");
 aux=(struct ccircular *)malloc(num*(sizeof(struct ccircular)));
 while (1)
 {
    printf("MENU\n 1.-Insertar \n 2.-Eliminar \n 3.-Mostrar \n 4.-Eliminar toda la cola  \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);system("cls");
 switch(ch)
 {
 case 1:
    printf("Ingrese elemento\n");
    scanf("%s",&x);
    push(aux,x,num);
    printf("Regresando en un segundo\n");Sleep(1000);
    break;
 case 3:
    muestracola(aux,x,num);
    printf("Regresando en un segundo\n");Sleep(1000);
    break;
  }

   }
```

Comment: Siempre te va a mostrar la primera letra porque eso es lo que estás asignando. Todo esto se ve en este código: `(aux+belem)->a=*x  ; `. Le estás dando al miembro `a` (que es de tipo `char`) el primer caracter al que apunte el puntero `x`.

Comment: Y como le mando toda la cadena?, disculpa

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el miembro `char a` a `char a[50]` (de la estructura `circular`). Posteriormente, usas la función `strcpy` para copiar los caracteres al que apunte `x` en el miembro `a`. Ej: `strcpy((aux+belem)->a, x);`

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias, trabajare en la funcion pop, al igual deberia usar strcpy para poder decir que elemento fue sacado, cierto?

Comment: Exactamente! :)

Comment: Ahora en la funcion pop `int pop(struct ccircular *aux,char x[],int num)` y al mostrar que elemento saque este pasa a marcar un caracter "?" gracias nuevamente

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta con el problema que tengas con la función pop.